# Problem in showing partial derivatives in a table

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'm writing the manuscript of my paper and I have to write partial derivatives in a table. While doing so, there is a problem when I use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` in table. For simplicity, I write a part of table as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
  Boundary &  Flow  \\
\midrule
  Inlet &   
  \[ \textit {u=U_0, v=0}\]\\
  Outlet & 
  \[  {\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0}\]\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I would be grateful if someone give me a help with this issue.
I have to mention that when I use the same equation NOT in table, the code is applied well:

```
\begin{equation}
 {\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: If any of your cell is `p{...}`, then the content is put in a parbox (paragraph box), so if you want a displayed math there, you can have it. `c`,`l`, etc. are set in *horizontal mode*, that is, like a line of text (no paragraphs), so displayed math doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, without equation numbers, with the `esdiff` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{c >{$}wc{3cm}<{$}}
    \toprule
      Boundary & \text{Flow} \\
    \midrule
      Inlet &
      u=U_0, v=0 \\[1ex]
      Outlet &
     \diffp{u}{y} =\diffp{v}{x} =0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From Bernard's nice answer, just a small change from `esdiff` package to `derivative` package (which I personally prefer), and use of `displaystyle` in the column definition to ensure math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{derivative}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
  \toprule
  Boundary & \text{Flow}                 \\
  \midrule
   Inlet   & u = U_0, v = 0              \\[1ex]
   Outlet  & \pdv{u}{y} = \pdv{v}{x} = 0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]